# docker-compose port not exposing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When i try to access my lambda endpoint from outside i receive this error:

> curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:3000/create-loan
>
> Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

But inside docker the endpoint work, the port 3000 does not working from outside.

Any help?

Name                    Command               State           Ports
billing_db_1       docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp

billing_lambda_1   /usr/local/bin/sam local s ...   Up      0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  lambda:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/billing 
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${BILLING_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${BILLING_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${BILLING_DB}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=${BILLING_HOST}
volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
```

**My DockerFile**:

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN pip3 install aws-sam-cli

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/sam"]

RUN apt-get install curl

RUN pip3 install pipenv

WORKDIR /app
RUN pipenv install --dev
CMD ["local", "start-api"]
```

**Solved**

```
CMD ["local","start-api","--host","0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 3):

By the compose file you've exposed the port 3001

```
ports:
  - "3001:3000"
```

But connecting to 3000

```
curl -XPOST 127.0.0.1:3000/create-loan
```

Comment: the 3001 was a test that i made, the solution is: CMD ["local","start-api","--host","0.0.0.0"]